# Bayesian inference for continuous prior and discrete likelihood

Tags: bayesian, continuous-data

I’m trying to wrap my head around an applied engineering problem which can be formulated in the following way.

There is a black box which produces exponentially distributed events $E$ with random intervals of time between them. It is known from observational data that the distribution of events by days of the week $D$ **is not** uniform.

I need an intuition how to calculate posterior $P(E|D_i)$ using Bayes formula, where:

- $P(E)$ determined by an exponential probability distribution with known $\lambda$.
- $P(D_i|E)$ supposed to be $\frac{\text{events at } D_i}{\text{total number of events}}$, if I'm not mistaken.
- And... calculation of $P(D)$ is totally unclear to me now.

Also, I have a gut feeling that using Bayes' theorem here is the wrong idea in general. Intuition tells me that $\lambda$ here is just an mean value over all $D$ and probably I just need to modify $\lambda$ somehow proportionally to get a better posterior estimation. Basically I need a higher posterior probability (than prior) for days where number of events more than average and vice versa.